# Problems with 2 different jquery scripts in safari, chrome, webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I will start off by saying I did not write this code, as jquery is not really my forte. I am having some problems with a couple of scripts in webkit browsers, and wondering if someone can help me. the site in question can be viewed at http://disalle.dev.activemls.com.

**Issue #1 equal height divs:**
I am using the following code and then assigning as follows id="leftcol" class="equal-height", and id="maincol" class="equal-height". Using the following, the script only appears to be working periodically:

```
<!--JQUERY EQUAL COLUMN HEIGHT-->
function resetHeight() {
   var maxHeight = 0;
   $(".equal-height").height("auto").each(function(){ 
       maxHeight = $(this).height() > maxHeight ? $(this).height() : maxHeight; 
   }).height(maxHeight);
}
resetHeight();
// reset height on resize of the window:
$(window).resize(function() { 
    resetHeight();
});
```

**Issue #2 dynamically selected option values:**
The following code is used to select which group of option values are displayed in a multi-select box based on  what is selected in the select box. When the page is first loaded the default option in the select box is "select a state" and the options are "ohio" or "michigan". In the defaults state the css is set to hide .ohio and .michigan content in the select box and then should display when selected. This works perfectly in Firefox, but again fails in webkit browsers. Here is the code:

**Jquery**

```
<!--JQUERY DYNAMIC SELECT BOX-->
$('.area-select').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
    $('.area-list').hide();
   $('.'+selected.val()).show(); 
    $('.optionvalue').html(selected.html());
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="spacer">
                        <label>Select A State</label><br />
                            <select class="area-select">
                                <option selected="selected" value="start">Select A State...</option>
                                <option value="ohio">Ohio</option>
                                <option value="michigan">Michigan</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spacer">
                        <label>Select An Area</label><br />
                            <select name="area" size="10" multiple="multiple">
                                <option class="area-list start" value="start">Select A State First...</option>
                                <!-- TMPL_LOOP Area_descs -->
                                <option class="area-list ohio" value="<!-- TMPL_VAR area_name -->">
                                <!-- TMPL_VAR area_name -->
                                </option>
                                <!-- /TMPL_LOOP -->
                                <!-- TMPL_LOOP Area_descs -->
                                <option class="area-list michigan" value="<!-- TMPL_VAR area_name -->">
                                <!-- TMPL_VAR area_name -->
                                </option>
                                <!-- /TMPL_LOOP -->
                            </select>
                    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ohio, .michigan {display:none;}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading jQuery equal columns script?

If you're using `$(document).ready(function()` then you should try `$(window).load(function()` instead.